# How to pass multiple parameters on onchange in blazor

Tags: parameters, blazor, onchange

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters to onchange event in blazor?.
If it is not possible, may I know what are my options. Thank you.

Requirement: User should have the ability to set color of their choice for each item. So, I need to pass additional parameter (itemNo) during each color selection.

Tried to pass extra parameter, but does not compile, throws error:

```
 <input bind=@colorSelected id="changeColor" type="color" value="#55BF3B"  @onchange="((ChangedEventArgs args) => HandleColorChange(args, itemNo))">

 void HandleColorChange(ChangeEventArgs args, int itemNo)
 {
    colorSelected = args.Value.ToString();         
   //I need to set color as below for one specific item
     item[itemNo] = colorSelected;          
 }
```

Current working Code, if no extra parameter passed:

```
  <input bind=@colorSelected id="changeColor" type="color" value="#55BF3B" @onchange="HandleColorChange">

  void HandleColorChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
  {
     colorSelected = args.Value.ToString();            
     //But I need to set this color for one specific item, for which I need to pass another parameter          
  }
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: You can wish to return the array ```item``` , you can use Eventcallback => please check at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#eventcallback 


if just on same razor page, just define ```private string[] item {get;set;}``` 
based on your working Code, add 1 line ```  item[itemNo] = colorSelected;  ``` 

I hope, it can help a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have working example:

```
@for(int i=0; i < item.Length; i++)
{
    int b = i;
    <div>
        <span>Selector for @i :</span>  <input bind=@colorSelected id="changeColor" type="color" value="#55BF3B"  @onchange="(args => HandleColorChange(args, b))">
    </div>
}

@for(int i=0; i < item.Length; i++)
{
    <div>
        <span>Selected for @i :</span> @item[i]
    </div>
}

@code
 {  
     string colorSelected = "blue";

     string [] item = new string[10];

    void HandleColorChange(ChangeEventArgs args, int itemNo)
    {
        colorSelected = args.Value.ToString();         
        item[itemNo] = colorSelected;     
    }
 }
```

https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QxEhlQle42JJ49dz28

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `@onchange` attribute then you need to use only `value` and `@onchange` attributes.

In your code you need to remove the `bind` attribute and set the value to your `@colorSelected` field.

```
<input id="changeColor" type="color" value="@colorSelected"  @onchange="((ChangeEventArgs args) => HandleColorChange(args, itemNo))">
```

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#:%7E:text=Pages/BindTheory.razor%3A)